# Coleman Liau index formula just will not work

Tags: python, computer-science, cs50

I'm writing readability in python for CS50, and I've tried so many different Coleman liau index formulas but it still will not work no matter what I do. My letter, word and sentence counters are giving me the correct output.

I've been trying for hours to the point where I just copied and pasted an algorithm I found still doesn't work... and translating from C doesn't work (from my old code) :/

```py
from cs50 import get_string

def count_sentences(text):
    index = 0

    length = len(text)

    amount_of_sentences = 0
    while index < length:
        if text[index] == '.' or text[index] == '!' or text[index] == '?':
            amount_of_sentences += 1

        index += 1

    return amount_of_sentences
def count_words(text):

    index = 0

    length = len(text)

    amount_of_words = 0
    while index < length:
        if text[index] == ' ':
            amount_of_words += 1

        index += 1
    amount_of_words += 1
    return amount_of_words

def count_letters(text):

    index = 0

    length = len(text)

    amount_of_letters = 0

    while index < length:
        if (text[index].isalpha() and text[index] == ' ') == False:
            amount_of_letters += 1

        index += 1


    return amount_of_letters



def algorithm(text):
    words = count_words(text)
    letters = count_letters(text)
    sentences = count_sentences(text)
    print(words, letters, sentences)
    return 0.0588 * (letters / words * 100) - 0.296 * (sentences / words * 100) - 15.8
text = get_string("Text: ")

grade_level = algorithm(text)
print(grade_level)
if grade_level < 1:
    print("Before Grade 1")

elif grade_level >= 16:
    print("Grade 16+")

else:
    print("Grade", round(grade_level))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my count_letters() function :/ . The  `and text[index] == ' ') == False` was the problem

````py
def count_letters(text):

    index = 0

    length = len(text)

    amount_of_letters = 0

    while index < length:
        if text[index].isalpha():
            amount_of_letters += 1

        index += 1


    return amount_of_letters```
````